# Lambda execution role

Tags: aws-lambda

I found a lambda function that will backup the instances periodically.

http://blog.powerupcloud.com/2016/10/15/serverless-automate-ami-creation-and-deletion-using-aws-lambda/

when I tried this function I got an error...

```
statusCode: 403, message: 'You are not authorized to perform this operation.'
```

May be because I chose "lambda_basic_execution" existing role. What is the correct Role to choose for this to run?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the correct permissions to the lambda_basic_execution role. The minimum required permissions are :
ec2:DescribeInstances,
ec2:CreateImage,
ec2:CreateTags,
ec2:DescribeImages,
ec2:DeregisterImage and
ec2:DeleteSnapshot

Comment: I tried with the new permissions and it still does not create AMI

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to be creating your own IAM execution role that has the exact permissions you need. Follow [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-create-iam-role.html).

Comment: What role should i use to invoke lambda function from aws lex? Currently default service linked role `AWSServiceRoleForLexBots` does not have permission to invoke lamda method.